# How do I make post requests to an S3 bucket using REST?

Tags: android, rest, amazon-s3, libgdx

I have an android game written in libGDX (a cross-platform java sdk), and I want to log session data and send it up to an s3 bucket. I don't want to use the aws mobile sdk because I want the application to be platform neutral. I can't find any documentation on this though. How do I make POST requests to s3 from java? I just want to write a new key-value pair to my bucket.

Comment: Which other platforms are you targeting?

Comment: Desktop, HTML5, iOS and Android. At least, we haven't broken it for any of them yet so would like to avoid doing so on principle unless there's some really compelling reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDKs make it easy to access the Amazon Web Services. In addition to the mobile SDKs, you have standalone SDKs for [Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), [PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) or [.Net](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/). If you prefer not using the SDKs, you can refer to the documentation of the [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html) for directly manipulating the buckets and objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Rajesh. I know about the REST API but I can't find a good tutorial on simple usage and it makes me think it's overkill for my android game. Also since I'm using libGDX to write my game, I don't want to write separate processes for desktop and mobile versions, as a rule if I can stick to it. All I want to do is push a short string to a database so I can aggregate some usage statistics. I'm now thinking that the best learning experience will be to make my own API on a server using django, which I'm a little bit familiar with and has a much richer set of tutorials.